# Stack Walk on linux using ptrace

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

Following is my requirement.

while process A is running.

1. attach Process A from B with PTRACE_ATTACH.
2. Start a Loop
3. Stop Process A
4. read registers
5. Resume Process A
6. sleep(1)
7. end loop
8. detach A

i am facing issue with Start and Resume Process A from the loop. i tried combination of kill(pid,SIGSTOP), kill(pid,SIGCONT), PTRACE_CONT. but didnt work.

any other solutions please?

Thanks in advance.
Sandeep

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxtoolsdev/thread/4f21d7d8-d30e-4754-a0f6-dc2da3b75c40

relevant link for windows..

Comment: kill() to stop and PTRACE_CONT is to continue is the right combination. Most debuggers use SIGINT (instead of SIGSTOP) to stop the process, you could try that. But I'm guessing that you made some other error, you'll have to post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Following code is working for me and seems to fulfill your requirements -

**A.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i=0;
   printf("My PID is - %ld\n",getpid());
   while(i>=0)
   {
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**B.c - Tracing process**

```
int main()
{
   int pid;
   int status;
   struct user_regs_struct regs;
   unsigned int eip;

   printf("Enter pid to trace : \n");
   scanf("%d",&pid);
   printf("PID to be traced - %ld\n",pid);

   ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH,pid,0,0);
   if(errno)
   {
        perror("attach");
        return -1;
   }

   waitpid(pid,&status,WUNTRACED);

   printf("Process Stopped\n");
   while(1)
   {
      ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS,pid,0,&regs);
      eip=ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT,pid,regs.eip,0);

      printf("EIP - 0x%08x, instruction executed - 0x%08x\n",regs.eip,eip);

      ptrace(PTRACE_CONT,pid,0,0);
      waitpid(pid,&status,WUNTRACED);
   }

   return 0;

}
```

Signal passed -

> kill -STOP 17779 
>   kill -STOP 17779

Output of A -

```
xxxxx!xxxxx:~/myPer/stack_overflow [135]$ ./A
My PID is - 17779
```

Output of B -

```
XXXXX!xxxxx:~/myPer/stack_overflow [121]$ ./B
Enter pid to trace :
17779
PID to be traced - 17779
Process Stopped
EIP - 0x080483e1, instruction executed - 0x00f87d83
EIP - 0x080483e5, instruction executed - 0x00b8fa79
EIP - 0x080483e5, instruction executed - 0x00b8fa79
```

We see that B displays EIP value for each signal delivered to client. Basically signal is not getting delivered to A instead B wakes up and examines EIP and then continues in the loop. You can modify the code to deliver the signal if you want.

This is what i understood from your question. If i understood something else please let me know and i'll update answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a very challenging project to undertake from scratch. Have you considered leveraging the [GNU debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) in any way? In particular there is an long running sub-project called [libgdb2](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdbint/libgdb.html#libgdb) which may suit your purposes even though it is far from finished or stable at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try scripting/interfacing with gdb in the same way that a lot of IDE's do. See also http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/gdb/gdb-mi.html