# See all the variables and their addresses CURRENTLY in the stack (gdb command)

Tags: c++, memory, assembly, gdb, memory-address

Is there a way to do this - not with just getting the last things that were in esp/rsp because when I use that in my program I also get the variables that were there but now there are not here. Thanks!

Comment: You may, but it's very much platform dependent.

Comment: This is a dupe if you want it [for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6205981/179910). Also a dupe if you want it [for Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3179487/179910).

Comment: i am sorry, i am talking about gdb command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `backtrace full` (or abbreviate to `bt full`) to get all the local variables from parent frames too.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by stack state, yes. It shows local variables that live on the stack. Assuming you have debug info for your program. Why not just try and see?

Comment: I have used this and doesnt help. Get this:#0  0x0000000000400838 in ret_arr() ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x000000000040085c in main ()
No symbol table info available.

Comment: Then you didn't compile with debug info.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. Thank you so much.